# Как отобразить wchar_t в int?

Tags: c++, linux, int, wchar-t

Всем привет.
Я хочу сделать, чтоб функция принимала русские символы(wchar_t) и превращала их в цифры(int), например, для сочитания или умножения и обратного превращения в символы. Но как только я попытался написать нечто подобное:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    wchar_t a;
    wchar_t b;
    
    wcin >> a >> b;
    wchar_t c=a+b;
    
    wcout << (int)a << endl;
    wcout << (int)b << endl;
    wcout << c << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

то возникла куча проблем, например, принимаемые русские символы не имели четкого значения и могли меняться непонятно от чего. Разные символы могли иметь одинаковые номера и так далее. Так вот, как преобразовывать из wchar_t в int и наоборот, чтоб с этим можно было работать?

Comment: Локаль надо правильную установить. Например, `setlocale(LC_ALL, "en_us.UTF-8");`. Естественно, русский язык в системе тоже д.б. установлен.  (Хотя, я предпочитаю не использовать wchar_t вовсе, работать с родной  utf-8 кодировкой в обычном char)

Comment: Под Windows таких неприятностей не видно :)

Comment: @avp Как найти правильную локаль? setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus"); или setlocale(LC_ALL, "ru.UTF-8"); не помогают. И если кратко то как тут можно было бы использовать utf-8 кодировку вместо wchar_t?

Comment: @SuitWhite, а какие локали у вас установлены? Посмотрите командами `locale` -- текущая установка, `locale -a` -- все, доступные сейчас в системе

Comment: Если в системе текущая локаль правильно работает с русским, то можно просто `setlocale(LC_ALL, "");` (кстати, setlocale возвращает строку с локалью, ее можно распечатать -- `puts(setlocale(LC_ALL, ""));`)

Comment: И еще, в русской локали обычно вместо десятичной точки используется запятая. Чтобы избежать проблем с этим маразмом, после `setlocale(LC_ALL, "");` имеет смысл вызвать `setlocale(LC_NUMERIC, "C");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
setlocale(LC_NUMERIC, "C");
```

Помогло. Спасибо [@avp](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/232/avp)